# Pronunciation of 'R' in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

How do I pronounce 'their' and 'there' in British English? Should the word 'there' have the 'r' letter pronounced as it is before a vowel sound?

Comment: The r in _there_ is not before a vowel sound unless the following word begins with a vowel sound.

Comment: See [Rhoticity in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what part of Britain you go to, but mostly the 'r' is not pronounced, except as a sort of "uh" sound e.g. "the-uh".